# Query returns 0 rows when it should return n results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm learning `SQL` using `PostgresSQL`.

I have a very simple query that in my understanding should return 3 results.

Here is the table (simplified because the one I parsed was all screwed up):

```
  fname   |  lname  |    ssn    | super_ssn 
----------+---------+-----------+-----------
 James    | Borg    | 888665555 | 
 John     | Smith   | 123456789 | 333445555
 Franklin | Wong    | 333445555 | 888665555
 Alicia   | Zelaya  | 999887777 | 987654321
 Jennifer | Wallace | 987654321 | 888665555
 Ramesh   | Narayan | 666884444 | 333445555
 Joyce    | English | 453453453 | 333445555
 Ahmad    | Jabbar  | 987987987 | 987654321
```

So, by looking into this, I know that there are three names there that should be managers, since they are present in the super_ssn column.

When I do:

```
SELECT fname, lname
FROM employee
WHERE super_ssn = ssn;
```

I get

```
 fname | lname 
-------+-------
(0 rows)
```

Why is that?

The column `ssn`, and the column `super_ssn` are both character types.

As I said, I'm learning it, so be slightly more in depth with your answer if you can. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no rows where:

```
WHERE super_ssn = ssn;
```

The `WHERE` clause only considers values *in the same row*.  Hence, your query returns no rows.

I suspect you want `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname
FROM employee e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM employee e2
              WHERE e2.super_ssn = e.ssn
             );
```

Comment: that part about the `WHERE` statement clarifies SO MUCH! I've read the documentation many times, but learning without continuous effort is such a pain. Thanks a bunch.